# FileStorage for OpenCV Python API

Tags: c++, python, image-processing, opencv

I'm currently using **FileStorage** class for storing matrices **XML/YAML** using OpenCV **C++** API.

However, I have to write a Python Script that reads those **XML/YAML** files.

I'm looking for existing OpenCV **Python API** that can read the **XML/YAML** files generated by **OpenCV C++ API**

Comment: in the latest version (after 3.1.0) python bindings for FileStorage/FileNode have been added: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/6482

Answer (score 23):

You can use [PyYAML](http://pyyaml.org/) to parse the YAML file.

Since PyYAML doesn't understand OpenCV data types, you need to specify a constructor for each OpenCV data type that you are trying to load.  For example:

```
import yaml
def opencv_matrix(loader, node):
    mapping = loader.construct_mapping(node, deep=True)
    mat = np.array(mapping["data"])
    mat.resize(mapping["rows"], mapping["cols"])
    return mat
yaml.add_constructor(u"tag:yaml.org,2002:opencv-matrix", opencv_matrix)
```

Once you've done that, loading the yaml file is simple:

```
with open(file_name) as fin:
    result = yaml.load(fin.read())
```

Result will be a dict, where the keys are the names of whatever you saved in the YAML.

Comment: @misha do you know why it gives this warning? `comparison to 'None' will result in an elementwise object comparison in the future. if data in [None, ()]:`

Comment: Add @vishal's advice about stripping the first line, and this answer would be perfect. Otherwise, python won't be able to read the file.

Comment: Also, set the data-type. Fortunately, the numpy data-type codes are the same as OpenCV's, at least for simple types like float and double.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I write .yml with c++ and read them as above.  The resulting numpy array isn't the same as the original (multidimensional) cv::Mat

Comment: Please view @TimSC's answer for the correct answer - the question specifically asks for the Python OpenCV API, this answer gives a convoluted PyYAML way of doing it.

Answer (score 9):

Using the FileStorage functions available in OpenCV 3.2, I've used this with success:

```
import cv2
fs = cv2.FileStorage("calibration.xml", cv2.FILE_STORAGE_READ)
fn = fs.getNode("Camera_Matrix")
print (fn.mat())
```

Comment: Do you know how to get list  of all available nodes?

Answer (score 8):

In addition to @misha's response, OpenCV YAML's are somewhat incompatible with Python.

Few reasons for incompatibility are:

1. Yaml created by OpenCV doesn't have a space after ":". Whereas Python requires it. [Ex: It should be `a: 2`, and not `a:2` for Python]
2. First line of YAML file created by OpenCV is wrong. Either convert "%YAML:1.0" to "%YAML 1.0". Or skip the first line while reading.

The following function takes care of providing that:

```
import yaml
import re
def readYAMLFile(fileName):
    ret = {}
    skip_lines=1    # Skip the first line which says "%YAML:1.0". Or replace it with "%YAML 1.0"
    with open(scoreFileName) as fin:
        for i in range(skip_lines):
            fin.readline()
        yamlFileOut = fin.read()
        myRe = re.compile(r":([^ ])")   # Add space after ":", if it doesn't exist. Python yaml requirement
        yamlFileOut = myRe.sub(r': \1', yamlFileOut)
        ret = yaml.load(yamlFileOut)
    return ret

outDict = readYAMLFile("file.yaml")
```

NOTE: Above response is applicable only for yaml's. XML's have their own share of problems, something I haven't explored completely.

Comment: Helpful tip. I tried change the line to "YAML 1.0" though, and it doesn't work. So you do have to strip the first line.

Comment: @orodbhen: Had you put the `%` before `YAML`?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, that was just a typo in my comment. With `%YAML 1.0` I get a ParseError. This is with `PyYAML 3.12` for `Python 3.6`.

Comment: Please view @TimSC's answer for the correct answer - the question specifically asks for the Python OpenCV API, which works just fine with the C++ generated YAMLs.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a small snippet to read and write FileStorage-compatible YAMLs in Python:

```
# A yaml constructor is for loading from a yaml node.
# This is taken from @misha 's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15942429
def opencv_matrix_constructor(loader, node):
    mapping = loader.construct_mapping(node, deep=True)
    mat = np.array(mapping["data"])
    mat.resize(mapping["rows"], mapping["cols"])
    return mat
yaml.add_constructor(u"tag:yaml.org,2002:opencv-matrix", opencv_matrix_constructor)

# A yaml representer is for dumping structs into a yaml node.
# So for an opencv_matrix type (to be compatible with c++'s FileStorage) we save the rows, cols, type and flattened-data
def opencv_matrix_representer(dumper, mat):
    mapping = {'rows': mat.shape[0], 'cols': mat.shape[1], 'dt': 'd', 'data': mat.reshape(-1).tolist()}
    return dumper.represent_mapping(u"tag:yaml.org,2002:opencv-matrix", mapping)
yaml.add_representer(np.ndarray, opencv_matrix_representer)

#examples 

with open('output.yaml', 'w') as f:
    yaml.dump({"a matrix": np.zeros((10,10)), "another_one": np.zeros((2,4))}, f)

with open('output.yaml', 'r') as f:
    print yaml.load(f)
```

Comment: This does not work anymore :   ```File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/representer.py", line 142, in ignore_aliases
    if data in [None, ()]:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()```

Answer (score 1):

To improve on the previous answer by @Roy_Shilkrot I added support for numpy vectors as well as matrices:

```
# A yaml constructor is for loading from a yaml node.
# This is taken from @misha 's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15942429
def opencv_matrix_constructor(loader, node):
    mapping = loader.construct_mapping(node, deep=True)
    mat = np.array(mapping["data"])
    if mapping["cols"] > 1:
        mat.resize(mapping["rows"], mapping["cols"])
    else:
        mat.resize(mapping["rows"], )
    return mat
yaml.add_constructor(u"tag:yaml.org,2002:opencv-matrix", opencv_matrix_constructor)


# A yaml representer is for dumping structs into a yaml node.
# So for an opencv_matrix type (to be compatible with c++'s FileStorage) we save the rows, cols, type and flattened-data
def opencv_matrix_representer(dumper, mat):
    if mat.ndim > 1:
        mapping = {'rows': mat.shape[0], 'cols': mat.shape[1], 'dt': 'd', 'data': mat.reshape(-1).tolist()}
    else:
        mapping = {'rows': mat.shape[0], 'cols': 1, 'dt': 'd', 'data': mat.tolist()}
    return dumper.represent_mapping(u"tag:yaml.org,2002:opencv-matrix", mapping)
yaml.add_representer(np.ndarray, opencv_matrix_representer)
```

Example:

```
with open('output.yaml', 'w') as f:
    yaml.dump({"a matrix": np.zeros((10,10)), "another_one": np.zeros((5,))}, f)

with open('output.yaml', 'r') as f:
    print yaml.load(f)
```

Output:

```
a matrix: !!opencv-matrix
  cols: 10
  data: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
  dt: d
  rows: 10
another_one: !!opencv-matrix
  cols: 1
  data: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
  dt: d
  rows: 5
```

Though I could not control the order of rows, cols, dt, data.

Answer (score 0):

pip install opencv-contrib-python for video support to install specific version use pip install opencv-contrib-python