# XML or YML parsing in OpenCV with Python

Tags: c++, python, xml, opencv, yaml

With openCV you can save/load data with YML or XML format. It is easy with `cv::FileStorage` using c++ API. I cannot make it work with python API.`

[Here](http://pastebin.com/YhrecFLr) is an example of an YML file created using opencv c++ API.

If someone succeed to load it with openCV python API, let me know !

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141336/filestorage-for-opencv-python-api. Please check that for other alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

I'm late to the party, but I didn't find any way to do it in pure Python, as the YAML files created by OpenCV (YAML 1.0) aren't wholly compatible, nor easily read with the YAML libraries available in Python (YAML 1.1).

The Python/OpenCV bindings exist, but are just a bunch of C methods with absolutely no documentation, so they're pretty much unusable at this point.

However, writing a small C extension and wrapping it in a class was pretty easy to do, so I suggest you try it out. In case you (or anybody else) still need it, I may be able to release the code of the small module I wrote that, I'll ask that at work on Friday.

To give you some ideas, here is how I use my module :

```
with FileStorage("my/file.yml") as fs:
  print(fs["string"])  # Prints the "string" string key
  print(fs["int"])     # Prints the "int" integer key
  print(fs["matrix”])  # Prints a matrix (read as a NumPy array)
```

Comment: Thx. Code module would be great! What wrapper did you use ?

Comment: Just plain C methods and a small Python class that makes them more useable. It's easier than using CTypes/Cython/whatever else as most OpenCV code samples are... in C++.

Comment: Can you please post the source for the extension and wrapper?

Comment: I meant to ask but totally forgot about this. Added to my todo list this time, I'll send the module next week when I can if they are okay ;)

Comment: @F.X. Any module available for testing ? :)

Comment: @F.X. it is now 2018 and still no module!