# yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning a directive

Tags: yaml, pyyaml

I use PyYAML to read a file, python code is:

```
with open('demo.yml') as f:
    dataMap = yaml.load(f)
```

demo.yml:

```
%YAML:1.0
my_svm: !!opencv-ml-svm
  svm_type: C_SVC
  kernel: { type:LINEAR }
  C: 1.
```

Then error is:

```
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning a directive
  in "demo.yml", line 1, column 1
expected alphabetic or numeric character, but found ':'
  in "demo.yml", line 1, column 6
```

Someone help me?

Answer (score 4):

The directive should be `%YAML 1.0` (with no colon). You also will need a "document start" (`---`) to separate your directives from the document. E.g.:

```
%YAML 1.0
---
my_svm: !!opencv-ml-svm
  svm_type: C_SVC
  kernel: { type: LINEAR }
  C: 1.
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried, but the new problem is

    yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning a plain scalar
      in "demo.yml", line 5, column 14
    found unexpected ':'
      in "demo.yml", line 5, column 18

why here `kernel: { type:LINEAR }` is not right?

Comment: OpenCV writes %YAML:1.0 and no --- when it outputs a yaml http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html, so that is an opencv bug?  Actually http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12058510/xml-or-yml-parsing-in-opencv-with-python addresses this.

Comment: @LucasW, yes, that's an opencv bug: http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2800401

Comment: Indeed opencv YAML implementation is incomplete, but that's not an opencv bug. Opencv creates YAML 1.0 files and PyYAML (YAML 1.1) is incompatible with YAML 1.0. In YAML 1.0 a directive is a "key:value" pair (http://yaml.org/spec/1.0/#id2558757) and colon without a space is allowed (http://yaml.org/spec/1.0/#id2489726).

Answer (score 1):

you can modify the yaml file created by opencv 3.0
file1 from opencv:

```
1 %YAML:1.0
2 my_svm: !!opencv-ml-svm
3   svm_type: C_SVC
4   kernel: { type:LINEAR }
5   C: 1.
6 ...
```

file2:

```
1 my_svm: opencv-ml-svm
2   svm_type: C_SVC
3   kernel: { type: LINEAR }
4   C: 1.
5 ...
```

file1 -> file2:

1. delete line 1
2. delete "!!opencv-ml-svm"
3. add space after "type:" in line 4

then you can use `yaml.load(filename)` to load your data.

Answer (score 0):

Use cv2.FileStorage

```
import cv2    
fs = cv2.FileStorage(file_path, cv2.FILE_STORAGE_READ)
fn = fs.getNode("my_svm")
print(fn) # use fn.mat() it contains matrix
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
from cv2 import cv
import numpy as np

filepath = "test.yml"
matrixA = np.array( cv.Load(filepath, cv.CreateMemStorage(), "matrixA") )
matrixB = np.array( cv.Load(filepath, cv.CreateMemStorage(), "matrixB") )
print "matrixA:", matrixA
print "matrixB:", matrixB
```

As seen in:
http://xudongai.blogspot.jp/2013/08/how-to-use-python-to-load-opencv-yml.html

Comment: This gives AttributeError: module 'cv' has no attribute 'Load' (using OpenCV 3.1 at least)