# Dumping Opencv Mat into a YAML file using python

Tags: python, opencv, yaml, mat

Does anyone know how to write a cv2 mat into a YAML file using python (**I am not looking for any loading... just to create a YAML file**). I used the serializer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141336/filestorage-for-opencv-python-api), but after many trials I don't know how to dump the image (I'm very new in Python, so that's why I don't get some of the things explained there)

I tried with

```
img = cv2.imread('Example.jpg',1)
text_file = open('document.yaml', "w")
text_file.write(yaml.dump(img))
```

and also with the Dumper function from [here](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation)

```
img = cv2.imread('seastar.jpg',1)
text_file = open('document.yaml', "w")
text_file.write(dump(img,Dumper=Dumper))
```

both give me the result: "TypeError: data type not understood"

and (this one tells me that the object is not callable)

```
img = cv2.imread('seastar.jpg',1)
text_file = file('document.yaml', "w")
yaml.dump(img,text_file)
print yaml.dump(img_text)
```

Comment: Until now I just used

Comment: You should leave out the thanks, and begging (please etc) from your questions (that is the no chit-chat the help->tour talks about). There is also edit history so don't include information about that you changed the question, when we need that info we can find it.

Answer (score 1):

Until now I just used numpy, omitting the serialization stuff...

```
with open(out, 'w') as f:
    yaml.dump(img_d.tolist(), f)
```

...But if there was a better way to do it, then I would be very thankful to you guys