# AttributeError: 'cv2.FileStorage' object has no attribute 'getNode'

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0

I am building a project based on python3.4 and opencv3.0 in the PycharmCE2017 on my Ubuntu14.04 machine. When running the code below,

```
import cv2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    savePath = "/home/s/Desktop/Imgcov/"
    filename = savePath + "depth.xml"
    fs = cv2.FileStorage(filename, cv2.FILE_STORAGE_READ)
    matrix = fs.getNode("data")
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'cv2.FileStorage' object has no attribute 'getNode'
```

How can I fix this? Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: try `fs['data']`, or see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11141336/5008845)

Comment: Unfortunately, the error turns into `TypeError: 'cv2.FileStorage' object is not subscriptable`. I will look into the link you posted. Thanks, @Miki

Comment: The `AttributeError` has been removed with the installation of **opencv-python** package. However, the `matrix` is empty  after running the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use opencv-python whose version over 3.2.