# How to parse YAML file correctly?

Tags: python, yaml

Hi I have problem to parse .yml file. I try parse YAML file which look like this:

```
%YAML 1.0
---
flow: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 256
   cols: 256
   dt: "2f"
   data: [ 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       ...]
```

I try parse it like this

```
# Read YAML file
with open(file_name, 'r') as stream:
   data_loaded = yaml.safe_load(stream)
   print(data_loaded)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag 'tag:yaml.org,2002:opencv-matrix'
  in "flow_field/u00000.yml", line 3, column 7
```

This is first time I use yml files so I really don´t know what to do with it. Thx for help...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FileStorage for OpenCV Python API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141336/filestorage-for-opencv-python-api)

Comment: `%YAML 1.0` is invalid. YAML 1.0 allowed for `%YAML:1.0` while later versions allow for `%YAML 1.1` etc. `%YAML 1.0` is not valid in any version, so while PyYAML might happen to load it, assume that this may break any time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify a constructor for the OpenCV data type that you are trying to load, because it doesn't exist by default in `PyYAML`:

```
import yaml

def meta_constructor(loader, node):
   return loader.construct_mapping(node)

yaml.add_constructor(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:opencv-matrix', meta_constructor)

with open(file_name, 'r') as stream:
   data_loaded = yaml.load(stream, Loader=yaml.Loader)

print(data_loaded)
```

Output:

```
{'flow': {'rows': 256, 'cols': 256, 'dt': '2f', 'data': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, '...']}}
```